# Accidentally rejected nvidia-cudnn license install with apt, now I can't uninstall it

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg

I tried installing nvidia-cudnn and was being a bit fast and lose with the prompts. I accidentally hit reject when trying to install it. Now when I try to uninstall I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt purge nvidia-cudnn -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  nvidia-cudnn*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 45.1 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 203730 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nvidia-cudnn (8.2.4.15~cuda11.4) ...
Purging cuDNN installation from /usr
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-cudnn (--remove):
 installed nvidia-cudnn package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-cudnn
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Manually removing `sudo rm -r /usr/share/doc/nvidia-cudnn` and `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-cudnn*` then `sudo apt purge nvidia-cudnn` doesn't seem to do the trick. When I try and install it again, i'm not prompted for the license anymore. I've tried rebooting in between "uninstalling" and reinstalling. Where is the license accepted/rejected information kept? How can I force it to prompt me with the license again?

Both before and after the messup I used this command to install cudnn `sudo apt install nvidia-cudnn`

Now all I get is:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-cudnn 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed
  nvidia-cudnn
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 13.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 45.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 nvidia-cudnn amd64 8.2.4.15~cuda11.4 [13.2 kB]
Fetched 13.2 kB in 0s (971 kB/s)        
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-cudnn.
(Reading database ... 203718 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-cudnn_8.2.4.15~cuda11.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-cudnn (8.2.4.15~cuda11.4) ...
Setting up nvidia-cudnn (8.2.4.15~cuda11.4) ...
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add the exact command you used to install it . Yes it matters.

Comment: Sorry! @David I've added the command.

Comment: Is it installed correctly now?

Comment: If you know which package is misinstalled, you could try dpkg-reconfigure to fix it

Comment: @David It's not. I still get errors trying to uninstall it. dpkg-reconfigure didn't seem to help. It just output `Purging cuDNN installation from /usr` and then `sudo apt remove nvidia-cudnn` gave the same error as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The uninstall process fails as the pre-removal script (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-cudnn.prerm`) returns non-zero exit status.
Inside, the pre-removal script calls
`update-nvidia-cudnn -p` located in `/usr/sbin/update-nvidia-cudnn`
which after line 164 (`echo Purging cuDNN installation from ${PREFIX}`) runs a command `purge_cudnn ${PREFIX}` that fails.

I was able to fix the issue by forcing `exit 0` from `update-nvidia-cudnn -p`, by adding `exit 0` after line 164 in file `/usr/sbin/update-nvidia-cudnn`.

To sum up, edit the end of file `/usr/sbin/update-nvidia-cudnn` to:

```bash
...
elif test "${DO_PURGE}" -ne 0; then
    echo Purging cuDNN installation from ${PREFIX}
    exit 0  # added
    purge_cudnn ${PREFIX}
fi
```

and the uninstall process becomes possible. Then if `nvidia-cudnn` is installed again, the installer will ask you again to agree to the license.

Comment: the `purge_cudnn` function in that file essentially runs `rm -rv ...` on a bunch of files, so by exiting before that you're skipping their removal and essentially doing nothing at all?

Answer (score 1):

To remove an app you have installed the correct way to do so is the reverse command of the install.

sudo apt install nvidia-cudnn

This is the command you used to do the install. Therefore the command to remove the app would be.

sudo apt remove nvidia-cudnn

A force remove is a bad idea and may leave bits behind.

Comment: remove gives me the same error as purge (see my question for full output) `Errors were encountered while processing: nvidia-cudnn`